# ¿Cómo verificar e incrementar el id para el registro en base de datos postgres?

Tags: java, postgresql, mvc, spring, hibernate

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente, el punto es registrar todas las acciones que realiza el usuario para ello estoy utilizando desde mi entidad lo siguiente:

```
  @Id
@GenericGenerator(name="gen" , strategy="increment")
@GeneratedValue(generator="gen")
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public int getId() {
    return this.id;
}
```

lo que permite que mi id vaya incrementando, el problema se da cuando se realizan varias acciones, por ejemplo de login, si dos usuarios ingresan solamente de un usuario se registra su actividad de login en la base de datos pero para el segundo usuario se muestra el mensaje de:

```
 ERROR: ERROR: llave duplicada viola restricción de unicidad «PK_audit»
 Detail: Ya existe la llave (id)=(78805).
```

¿Cuál debería ser el mejor procedimiento para que se identifique el último id ingresado y así hacer que las acciones se vayan registrando?

Mil disculpas si la pregunta no está clara y desde ya muchas gracias.

Gracias, de momento la PK está definida de la siguiente manera :

```
id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval(('"st_audit_id_seq"'::text)::regclass)
```

Comment: Si estás usando postgresql podrías definir la PK como serial y dejar que sea la base de datos la que asigne la ID

Comment: Gracias @PabloLozano, he editado mi pregunta y he añadido el como se encuentra definida la PK. Tal vez está algo mal?

Answer (score 0):

Ya que postgreSQL incrementa automáticamente el valor de id al insertar,puedes decirle a Hibernate que quieres usar la secuencia declarada:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "st_audit")
@javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_ST_AUDIT", sequenceName = "st_audit_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
public class StAudit  {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_ST_AUDIT")
    private Integer id;

    ...
}
```